# Prompt a delete pop up window to confirm the delete - GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When the user clicks the Delete Button from the Command Field I need to prompt a window and ask: "Are you sure you want to delete Joe Smith?"

I wrote on the client side but I need the name of the row to display also.

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True"
        HeaderText="Action" />
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server"
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?');"
                AlternateText="Delete" />               
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my code for the delete row. Is there anyway to code the prompt in this method? Or I need to do a RowDataBound.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnection"];
        SqlConnection connDel = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        int User_ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM DoNotPay_Email_List WHERE User_ID=" + User_ID + "", connDel);
        connDel.Open();
        int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        /* if (temp == 1)
         {
             lblMessage.Text = "Record deleted successfully";
        }*/
        BindGrid();
        cmd.Dispose();
        connDel.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = (ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do it in Row_Deleting because that is running server side; you would need to go through multiple postbacks for each delete operation if you went that route.

You need to set the OnClientClick property in the RowDataBound event, where you have access to the bound row values and can concatenate your message to include whatever data you want.

Edit: take a look at the RowDataBound code in step 3, it will show you how to get a reference to the button, retrieve the row data, and customize the prompt text.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx